# centered image but text is under image

Tags: html, css, image, center

using this css I am able to center the image, however, the image now floats on top of the text. Originally I had the top at 0 all around, but these dimensions get the image correctly centered.  What can I do to keep the next line of text below the image and not under?

```
img.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px; bottom:50px; left: 105px; right:105px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: add jsfiddle example

Comment: If your content is static, you can set the top on the element containing your text, but absolute positioning is a pain to maintain if your image will ever get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning takes the image "out of the flow". To keep it in the document flow you could use something like:

If you know the height of the parent:

```
.parent {
    line-height: 100px;
}
.parent img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If you don't know the height:

```
.parent {
    display: table;
}
.parent img {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```